# How to authenticate from a bookmarklet in Yesod / How to add OPTIONS to Auth subsite of Yesod

Tags: haskell, bookmarklet, yesod

I wanted to access a server API I made with Yesod 1.2 from a bookmarklet. I wanted to `POST` from the bookmarklet at any other sites. The server API has an authentication (by Mozilla Persona and Google ID). This means:

- The server has to accept a cross-origin request from a bookmarklet.
- The server needs authentication for the API access from the bookmarklet.

I added `OPTIONS` to my Handler according to the following.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

[Allowing cross-origin requests in Yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774833/allowing-cross-origin-requests-in-yesod)

I noticed, however, that the request is forwarded to `/auth/login` of the Yesod app, even after the user is logged in from the browser (I think this makes sense because these two are different domains). Auth is handled in a subsite. So I think I need `OPTIONS` for `/auth/login` as well. How can I add OPTIONS for Auth subsite in `config/routes` file?

Or, is there any better way to have authentication from a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches:

1. Send a pull request for yesod-auth to include OPTIONS.
2. Use a middleware to handle that request.

I'd go for (1), you'll be benefiting the community and it will be easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have only used yesod-auth as a black box, but this will be a good chance for me to look into the source code in more detail.

Comment: Hey Hiro -- I am going to be diving into the same thing in the next week or two.  Want to compare notes?  If so, shoot me a note, c at getloxley dot com.