# Cross Origin Requests in Snap Framework

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Does anyone have any experience using cross-domain requests using Snap Framework. I'm new to using the framework and have found something for Yesod ([Allowing cross-origin requests in Yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774833/allowing-cross-origin-requests-in-yesod)) but I'm not sure how to do it for Snap. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the appropriate headers using Snap's [header manipulation functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.9.4.0/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#g:9).